# Will installing BURG bypass the Freya 0.3.1 bootloader bug?

Tags: release-freya, grub

As many, I had to spend some time fixing up the grub-2.02beta bootloader after fresh 0.3.1 install. After many hours of trying to fix it (at the time I didn't know that it was officially recognised bug and thought I had messed up with the install) I finally got it fixed. And now my x220 has a functioning dual boot. But... I want a nice graphical dual boot and I found BURG installation guide.

Now my question is, will using BURG bypass the grub-2.02beta or are they somehow related to each other? And if BURG fails will there be a shell where I can somehow boot the system like with grub?

Comment: I would not recommend installing Burg because development of it stopped. If you look at [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/burg) you can see that the last edit was in 2013. This can create some serious issues. For example: Burg does not support EFI/UEFI and it has some mayor flaws with some graphic drivers.

Comment: With that in mind, maybe rEFInd would be better solution instead of grub?